# Tag synonyms and descriptions

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We already have "doubled" tags like lp and linear-programming.

Can we define standard tags or is it too early for that?

Answer (score 8):

No, it isn't too early. If you notice tags that are duplicates, you want tags to be merged, synonymized, be removed, etc., come to Meta, here, ask a question with your request stated clearly and tag with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request)/[retag-request](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request)/[burninate-request](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

A moderator will see the post and will proceed accordingly. Please note that you should ask one request per post!