# What should our tags look like?

Tags: discussion, tags

related: [Tag synonyms and descriptions](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/tag-synonyms-and-descriptions)

Should the main tag for linear programming be [lp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lp) or [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming)?

[mip](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mip) or [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) or [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming)?

[sp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp) or [stochastic-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-programming)?

Note: this is about whether tags for classes of optimization models should be full length (linear-programming) or abbreviations (lp). It is not a request to delete or merge anything yet.

Comment: As mentioned, please create separate Meta posts for each one! We can't handle all of them in a single question! For now, edit the post to leave only one request and create other 2 with the other ones. Thanks.

Comment: I meant to have a general discussion about whether we should use abbreviations or the full length tags. After the discussion comes to a conclusion we can then create a meta post for every individual tag do be merged/removed.

Comment: Check stats and math.SE for the tag and try to use the same tags (and Wiki defined meaning) as they do, for programming related tags there's a half dozen CompSci sites - very short tags ( < 4 letters) usually aren't without confusion (for *someone*) and longer (even hyphenated) tags are better (esp. when there's a great Wiki summary).

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that for *types of optimization problems*, we use the full name, and the most common one; so: [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming), [integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming),  [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming), etc.

~~Also, "program", not "<s>programming</s>".~~

Tags must be <=35 characters. So we will start to have problems with things like [quadratically-constrained-quadratic-program](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratically-constrained-quadratic-program); in that case we'll probably have to use [qcqp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qcqp) or maybe [qc-quadratic-program](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qc-quadratic-program).

Comment: Hmm, I don't think tags should be half-abbreviated and half-expanded, but that's just my opinion...

Comment: Maybe, but some tags will surely have to be abbreviated ([stochastic-bilevel-mixed-integer-nonlinear-program]? I'm being a little facetious, but I'm sure some of them are going to get long.) So does that mean we should fully abbreviate those? And if so, should we fully abbreviate *all* of them for consistency?

Comment: I guess -program vs -programme vs -programming is a whole other topic in itself..

Answer (score 2):

I think very short tags such as [lp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lp) or [sp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp) should be turned into their full names, as they could be misinterpreted for another tag with the same starting letters, as the number of tags increases. Furthermore, "lp" and "sp" by themselves (and in lowercase) are not very commonly used so I would be against their abbreviations.

I guess the same goes for tags with three letters, although this can be controversial. I'll leave it open for others to discuss.

Tags such as [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) should be kept as such. If expanded, the tag will be too long, and MILP is quite a common abbreviation in operational research.

Comment: I would say that "lp" and "sp" are commonly used, but of course this is just from personal experience. I agree that expanding "milp" would be too long. But I would also prefer to have consistency among the more commonly used tags.

Comment: There should be an option to introduce an abbreviation for the full-length tags such that users can decide in their settings whether they want to see the short of the full version of tags. However, I guess this is outside our reach.

Comment: @Michiel You can raise it on Meta.SE if it hasn't been asked before :)

Comment: @Michiel those are tag synonyms. I think it's reasonable for [lp] to be a synonym for [linear-program], etc.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire would it make sense to post your list/image on a new meta thread? That way folks can comment on the individual tags more easily. This thread seems to be more focused on the question of abbreviating vs. not.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Good idea. One problem I see with this is that every now and again the image will have to be updated.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes, things are moving *fast* around here. :)