# Synonymise [lp] and [linear-programming]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, retag-request

The site was launches just a few hours ago, so the tags are messy. I found the [lp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lp) and [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) tags which are about exactly the same thing. LP is an abbreviation of linear programming, so I propose the tags to be synonymized.

Note: Please post an answer supporting which tag should be the master: [lp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lp) or [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) should be the master. It is more intuitive, self-explanatory, and easy to read. [lp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lp) can be a synonym.

It seems that folks prefer [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) to [linear-program](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-program), so I will retract [my suggestion to omit the -ing](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/55/38).

Comment: Yeah, [linear-programming] is much better. Let's keep this!