# Synonymise [mixed-integer-programming] and [milp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, retag-request

The tags [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming) and [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) have the same meaning, therefore I propose to synonymise of them. Also, note that there have been some arguments to also use [mip](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mip).

Please add an answer below supporting which should be the master: [mip](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mip), [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) or [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming) should be the master, for similar reasons as I mentioned for [[linear-programming] here](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/58/38).

I also think that both [mip](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mip) and [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) should be synonyms.

There might be some controversy over including [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) as a synonym. A MIP is a mixed-integer programming problem and could be linear or nonlinear; a MILP is specifically linear. But, in common usage, I think most people assume a MIP is linear, and they specify MINLP if the problem is nonlinear. So, I propose that [milp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milp) is a synonym for [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming).