# Synonymise [tsp] and [traveling-salesman]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, retag-request

I've already seen the [tsp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsp) tag on the site but not [traveling-salesman](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman). I think the least is to synonymize them. Similarly, we can do that for [vrp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrp) and [vehicle-routing](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-routing).

Please add an answer below supporting which should be the master: [tsp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsp), [traveling-salesman](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman)?

P.S: Since at the time of posting this, there is still no conclusion on whether to include the word "problem" for classical problems as mentioned [here](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/problem-in-tags/85#85), I left them out of my tag suggestions.

Comment: Related discussion: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-should-our-tags-look-like

Comment: these days it is traveling salesperson.

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke the same conversation happened below under Larry's post ;)

Comment: Should we also add [tag:bin-packing] and [tag:bpp]?

Comment: @mrBen I'm not too keen on `bpp` as it's not as widely-used, IMO, as the other abbreviations. However, you can create a new post and suggest that and let the community decide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd vote for [traveling-salesman](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman) being the master and [tsp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsp) being a synonym. Same for [vehicle-routing](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-routing) (master) and [vrp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrp) (synonym).

Comment: traveling-salesman is also called salesperson, saleswoman, sales agent, etc. etc. So maybe just tsp? In the description it can shortly mention traveling salesperson..

Comment: Personally I think [tsp] is too abbreviated, and non-intuitive to newcomers. Although the problem goes by other names, traveling salesman is by far the most common, and I think that makes the most sense as the tag.

Comment: The valid spelling as per English rules is travel**l**ing, not traveling, right?

Comment: No, one L for US English.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought this rule applied also for US-English